# redirect one url to another url with data .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

It's shame but I can't do this and I've to ask for your help...

I'm trying to redirect URL:
**`http://example.com/web/sim/good.php`** to **`http://example.com/good`**

It's simple (***`RewriteRule ^good$ /web/sim/good.php [L]`***)

But on this page I'd like use GET or POST metod with data (GPD), so I need redirect once again? I need a character like that:
**`http://example.com/good/GPD`** or **`http://example.com/good/ok/GPD`**.

I'd like the action on my site will be friendly or empty like this: 
*`form method="GET" action="" id="form"`*

I tried many things like this 
**`RewriteRule ^good/ok/(.+)$ /web/sim/good.php?data=$1`** etc. but it doesn't work.

I'm thinking and trying so long, can anyone help me with this?
**Thank you so much in advance for your help!**

<sup>EDIT: I'm new here, although I've been watching and reading many questions and answers for a very long time. I didn't set up an account until today cause I was always made what I need with the information I found. I see that people point out that my question is "doesn't show any effort or unclear or not useful," so I'm explaining. I'm trying do this for a few days in various ways but I can't. But if something is unclear then please ask, I think I've described it accurately enough. Unhelpful? Necessary for me so maybe for others too.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

you must be out `header` use it.
and put your desired amount inside.
for example:

```
<?php 
     if(isset($_POST["url"])){ 
         header("Location: https://example.com/{$_POST['url']}");
     }
```

Comment: In this way I also tried but unfortunately I don't get what I need. But thank you for your good intentions. Btw. someone has decided that your answer isn't useful but I know it works because on another page I use this method and it's sufficient.